# SpringBoot - Run a @Configuration only if a certain property is defined using @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, annotations

I need to run a certain configuration only when a certain property is defined in my application.yml.
I found the @Conditional annotation that seems could do the work. I need the configuration to be created only if a issuer-uri is given to the app in a .env.

```
 * Configuration for OAuth 2.0 token validation
 */
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri")
@Order(2)
public class ApiSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /*
     * Issuer URI
     */
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuerUri;
```

The issue i'm getting is when the issuer-uri is not provided, the @Value seems to be evaluated before the @Conditional, so i'm getting :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ISSUER_URI' in value "${ISSUER_URI}"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add **matchIfMissing = false** to skip the configuration if the property is not available

```html
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri", matchIfMissing = false)
```